# How to prove the application working on web farm?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, worker-process

I have created a application that is the custom session mode and session bridge between asp and asp.net application. Now, I need to prove that is working or not. So, I have created an asp.net page. In this page, I had written this code.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess.Id
```

This produces worker process id. I can prove the application working on web farm due to changing worker process. But I don't know how to produce worker process id from classic asp. Please tell me. How can I get worker process id from classic asp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered setting a custom HTTP Response Header on each of the IIS servers in the web farm then displaying the value on the page? Like so:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers["X-ServerName"]
```

Where X-ServerName is the custom HTTP Response Header on each of the IIS Servers.

EDIT:
Sorry, for Classic ASP you can try using javascript in the page to get the header.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', document.location, false);
req.send(null);
var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();
alert(headers);
```

Comment: That is asp.net, no asp. I want to proof for classic asp.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I updated the answer to reflect a way of doing it in Classic ASP.